# Display Loading Gif While Macro Is Running

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I want display loading macro gif while macro runs behind
the problem is the loading GIF doesn't move during macro execution
As of now this is all I got from the internet

```
Private Sub btnFetchFiles_Click ()    
iRow = 14
fPath = Sheet1.txtPath.Text    
UserForm3.Show
'vbModeless
UserForm3.Caption = "LOADING"
UserForm3.Repaint
DoEvents
'vbModeless

'macro located here

   Unload UserForm3    
End Sub
```

Comment: How does your macro body look?

Comment: I attached the macro snipshot

Comment: Try insert a DoEvents into `ListFilesInFolder` and `ResultSorting`. You can also try to use a timer that refreshes the UI or calls DoEvents. Basically when you execute anything in a long running loop you have to pump the message queue with DoEvents to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: it shows the list updating but GIF still not moving

Comment: when I remove 

UserForm3.Caption = "LOADING"
UserForm3.Repaint

the GIF moves but it doesn't executes macro unless I closed it